# How to count cell ? google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet with 2 columns, the first one with names and the second one with numbers from 1 to 500

Using google app script, I would like to write a script which gives the number of cells with a value greater than 25 and display the result in another cell (for example D2).

I can't figure out how to write a function with if and count.

Comment: Are you trying to learn Google apps scripting, or you just want the result, no matter how? I ask because you actually don't need a script for that. Just use the `COUNTIF` function in your D2 cell.

Comment: I would like to use a script :)

Answer (score 2):

Get the array range and values.

```
var values = range.getValues(); //GetB:B column Values
var filtered = values.filter(morethan25); //Filter if more than 25
var count = filtered.length 

function morethan25(e) { return e[0]>25;}
```

Now,setValue() the count in D2.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need google script for doing this. Add this formula `=COUNTIF(B1:B1000,">25")` to D2 and D2 will get the count of number of cells with value greater than 25.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However is it possible to get this result using google app script ?